# No sound after ubuntu upgrade to 20.04

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I have to do `sudo alsa force-reload` to let my system detect my soundcard, before I only got shown a dummy output. But everytime I reboot I have to do this again. I already tried reinstaling alsa-base.

**Edit:**
`sudo systemctl status alsa-restore.service`
returns:

```
● alsa-restore.service - Save/Restore Sound Card State
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/alsa-restore.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (exited) since Wed 2020-10-07 17:23:42 CEST; 1min 19s ago
   Docs: man:alsactl(1)
Process: 1285 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /run/alsa (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 1319 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore (code=exited, status=99)
Main PID: 1319 (code=exited, status=99)

Okt 07 17:23:42 PhilippN-Vostro-5490 alsactl[1319]: Found hardware: "sof-hda-dsp" "Realtek ALC3204" "HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000 HDA:10ec0236,10280959,00100002 cfg-dmics:2" "" ""
Okt 07 17:23:42 PhilippN-Vostro-5490 alsactl[1319]: Hardware is initialized using a generic method
Okt 07 17:23:42 PhilippN-Vostro-5490 systemd[1]: Starting Save/Restore Sound Card State...
Okt 07 17:23:42 PhilippN-Vostro-5490 systemd[1]: Finished Save/Restore Sound Card State.
```

**Edit 2:**
`journalctl -b | grep alsa` returns:

```
Nov 05 16:44:28 Vostro-5490 systemd-udevd[586]: controlC0: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore 0' failed with exit code 99.
Nov 05 16:44:29 Vostro-5490 alsactl[1353]: alsa-lib parser.c:2157:(load_toplevel_config) Unable to find the top-level configuration file '/usr/share/alsa/ucm2/ucm.conf'.
Nov 05 16:44:29 Vostro-5490 alsactl[1353]: alsa-lib main.c:997:(snd_use_case_mgr_open) error: failed to import hw:0 use case configuration -2
Nov 05 16:44:29 Vostro-5490 alsactl[1353]: Found hardware: "sof-hda-dsp" "Realtek ALC3204" "HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000 HDA:10ec0236,10280959,00100002 cfg-dmics:2" "" ""
Nov 05 16:44:29 Vostro-5490 alsactl[1353]: Hardware is initialized using a generic method
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

Before you go with the custom service below, the way alsa reloads your configureation is by checking if `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` exists and what is in it (your list of sound devices) , through the systemd `alsa-restore.service` that runs at boot (to reload your configuration) and at shutdown (to preserve your last configuration)

It is essential to first check whether that particular service exists with

```
sudo systemctl status alsa-restore.service
```

and the status should report

```
alsa-restore.service - Save/Restore Sound Card State
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/alsa-restore.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2020-09-27 11:43:13 EDT; 5h 43min ago
       Docs: man:alsactl(1)
   Main PID: 755 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 11833)
     Memory: 0B
     CGroup: /system.slice/alsa-restore.service

Sep 27 11:43:13 FOOT systemd[1]: Starting Save/Restore Sound Card State...
Sep 27 11:43:13 FOOT systemd[1]: Finished Save/Restore Sound Card State.
```

The alsa-restore.service located in `/lib/systemd/system/alsa-restore.service` should look like so:

```
#
# Note that two different ALSA card state management schemes exist and they
# can be switched using a file exist check - /etc/alsa/state-daemon.conf .
#

[Unit]
Description=Save/Restore Sound Card State
Documentation=man:alsactl(1)
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/alsa/state-daemon.conf
ConditionPathExistsGlob=/dev/snd/control*
After=alsa-state.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=-/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore
ExecStop=-/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime store
```

if this service exists, but is disabled, you can enable and start it with

```
sudo systemctl enable alsa-restore.service
sudo systemctl start alsa-restore.service
```

If `sudo systemctl status alsa-restore.service` reports some additional error in its status that causes it to fail, that may need to be solved first.

---

---

#### Option 2

After double-checking `alsa force-reload` is not a oneshot command wrapper for `alsactl` but instead it is responsible for the restart of the corresponding alsa service, which occurs in two steps, first stopping, then starting it again.

To summarize, `sudo alsa force-reload` does is the following

1. Checking if the command `alsactl` can be located, and if not it exits right away
2. Running a script located at `/usr/share/alsa/utils.sh` which provides some indexing functions among other things.
3. Checking if  `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` exists
4. Running `alsactl -E HOME="$ALSACTLHOME" -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="${ALSACTLRUNTIME}" restore $CARD >/dev/null 2>&1` to restore volume states for each card found in `asound.state`

Step #4 is exactly what the `alsa-restore.service` executes on boot and shutdown under proper operation, hence all the issues point to it being disabled or not there at all.

We already know that `alsactl` exists on your system because `alsa force-reload` works, but **Next time you reboot and your audio is not automatically reloaded, instead of using `alsa force-reload` , try running from terminal:**

```
sudo /usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore
```

If this command restores your audio, then this is what you want to run at startup as a service (and its corresponding version to also run at shutdown), at appropriate moment.

Hence, if `alsa-restore.service` does not exist on your system, you should then and only then create your own `myaudio.service` like so:

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/myaudio.service`

Copy the following into it:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Audio
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/alsa/state-daemon.conf


[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=-/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore
ExecStop=-/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime store
RemainAfterExit=true


[Install]
WantedBy=sound.target
```

Saving it, followed by:

```
sudo systemct enable myaudio.service 
sudo systemctl start myaudio.service 
sudo systemctl status myaudio.service
```

Which will enable, start and report the status of your new service. If the 3 commands complete without errors, then you can reboot and test it.

Comment: This didn't work. After bootscreen I got only a black screen with my mouse on it. My touchpad doesn't work, but with my mouse i can move my mouse on black screen. I randomly found out, that when i press f12 while boot screen, my system boots normally, I can login but the Audio still isn't working. I logged in this way and disabled the service and removed the .service file. now i can boot normally without pressing F12, but my Audio still isnt working. Do you hve any Ideas left?

Comment: Sorry. my mistake. The reason `systemd` service failed (although it should not have prevented boot) was because of the `Type=oneshot` designation in the script, which allows for more than one command on the same line in the `ExecStart=` line. I'm going to update the script, and add a line explaining how to test the service before rebooting to make sure it works.

Comment: `systemctl status alsa-restore .service` returns additional to your  example output this line: `Process: 1356 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore (code=exited, status=99)`

Answer (score 0):

This message ¨code=exited, status=99¨ is probably due to not being a member of the audio group.

> sudo usermod -a -G audio username

Then reboot and check with:

> journalctl -b | grep alsa

Comment: logout is enough instead of rebooting.

Comment: this didn't work. see edit 2 in my Question